# Controlador web api con .Net Webforms no recibe datos en produccion

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, webapi, restsharp

Estoy usando `.Net webforms` en el que tengo un controlador web Api al que envio unos parametros por Post. El proyecto funciona bien cuando hago pruebas en desarrollo, debugo. Cuando subo el proyecto al IIS el controlador web Api no recibe datos.

Esta es la llamada que hago a mi controlador web api llamado "`MiwebServiceController.cs`"  usando la libreria RestSharp:

```
string urlBase = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.Replace(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.PathAndQuery, "");
string url = urlBase + "/Api/Miwebservice";
string parametrosJson = "{ \"p1\": \"parametro uno\" }";
RestRequest request = new RestRequest() { Method = Method.Post };
request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
request.AddParameter("application/json", parametrosJson, ParameterType.RequestBody);
var client = new RestClient(url);
var response = client.Execute(request);
var jsonString = response.Content();
```

En el `jsonString` cuando estoy en desarrollo haciendo pruebas recibo datos del controlador web api. En cambio cuando subo el desarrollo al `IIS` el controlador web api no recibe ningún parámetro post.

Resumo:

La llamada la hago desde el mismo proyecto. Del codebehind de la página aspx al controlador api web que esta en el mismo proyecto. Si la url es `localhost` funciona. Si subo el proyecto al `IIS`, el dominio del controlador api web ya deja de ser `localhost` para ser del tipo https://midominio.com/Api/Miwebservice

Creo que el problema es que cuando estoy en producción y recibe la url del dominio donde esta el codigo que es "`https://midominio.com/Api/Miwebservice`" y se la paso a `RestSharp` no entro al metodo POST del controlador Miwebservice o no entro al controlador Miwebservice. Pero en cambio si el dominio es "`https://localhost:44394/Api/Miwebservice`" si que entra al controlador API y al método POST del controlador para recibir el json.

En el método POST del controlador `Miwebservice` lo tengo declarado como :

```
public JObject Post([FromBody] JObject value)
```

Por algun motivo que desconozco cuando publico la pagina en el IIS en esa maquina no puedo acceder a la URL del dominio. Pero desde fuera del servidor esa URL si que se puede ver. ¿ Hay alguna manera de ver la pagina en un navegador que corra en el mismo servidor donde esta alojado el IIS? Porque creo que es este el problema que tengo.

Comment: en que linea da el error? ese parametrosJson  se transforma en json automaticamente???

Comment: @gbianchi no da error. Cuando paso el proyecto a producción y se llama al apiweb este no recibe ningun parametro. En cambio en desarrollo si que funciona porque recibe parametros del post.

Comment: @gbianchi se llama a la apiweb pasandole el string parametrosJson por POST luego en el controlador api cuando recibe string parametrosJson se parsea para coger el parametro 'p1'. Cuando el proyecto lo tengo en desarrollo 'localhost' el api web recibe el string parametrosJson con el parametro 'p1'. Cuando el proyecto lo tengo en produccion en IIS con un dominio el string parametrosJson que tendria que recibir por POST esta vacio.

Comment: @gbianchi correcto, la peticion la hago desde codebehind. El controlador Api web y el metodo donde esta el codigo que uso con la libreria RestSharp estan en el mismo proyecto. Estan en el mismo 'localhost'. He vuelto a editar la pregunta.

Comment: En el response, que vuelve?

Comment: @gbianchi el response me devuelve lo siguiente: "RestSharp.RestResponse". Si  imprimo el  response.StatusCode me devuelve 0. Si imprimo  response.Content me devuelve una cadena vacia o sea nada. Creo que RestSharp no llega al controlador web api cuando esta el proyecto en produccion puede ser que no encuentre la url que le estoy pasando. Pero esa url que le paso es real y existe.

Comment: Prueba con `string url = "/Api/Miwebservice";` y con `string url =  "https://localhost/Api/Miwebservice";`, porque a mi me da la impresión que es un tema de rutas. Por otro lado, probaste el endpoint con postman ??

Comment: @Yussef la url la obtengo bien pues en localhost me devuelve "https://localhost:44394/Api/Miwebservice" y en IIS me devuelve "https://midominio.com/Api/Miwebservice". El codigo para obtener la url es el siguiente HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.Replace(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.PathAndQuery, "") + "/Api/Miwebservice". No lo he probado con Postman lo hare como dices a ver

Comment: La URL puede ser correcta, pero la solicitud puede no ir y volver por temas de red (alguna configuración con el router o firewall). Yo esto lo he visto, software que no tiene acceso a si mismo mediante su nombre de dominio o ip publica, ni idea del motivo porque no se de redes

Comment: haz la prueba al IIS con localhost, http://localhost/Api/Miwebservice, si te funciona lo que puede no estar funcionando es el DNS público

Comment: @LPZadkiel como he escrito mas arriba cuando hago la prueba del proyecto con el IIS Express de Visual Studio la url es un https con  localhost:44394 y funciona perfectamente. Cuando el https es con el dominio del IIS midominio.com no funciona

Comment: esa prueba es con el IDE (probablemente visual studio), yo te digo ya instalado en el IIS la url local (en la máquina del IIS) debería ser https://localhost/Api/Miwebservice, digamos cuando instalas la web app en el iis en el panel derecho hay una opción que dice "Browse..." si le haces clic te hable la web app en localhost del iis

Comment: al hacer esto también se pueden ver detalles de debug si algo no está funcionando

Comment: @LPZadkiel desde dentro del IIS le he puesto como URL  el https://localhost/Api/Miwebservice y tampoco funciona

Comment: @LPZadkiel Tambien he probado con /Api/Miwebservice y el mismo resultado no encuentra la URL

Comment: Justo acaba de aparecer una pregunta que retrata el problema que yo mencionaba https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/611263/al-publicar-pagina-web-con-iis-no-puedo-acceder-al-dominio-de-la-pagina-dentro-d,  que según alguna configuración el servidor no puede acceder a si mismo

Comment: @Yussef sabes alguna forma de solucionarlo?

Comment: Me acabo de dar cuenta que eres el mismo usuario de la otra pregunta xD. Entonces comprobaste que es un tema de redes. Debes probar si puedes entrar por `https://localhost/Api/Miwebservice` o `https://127.0.0.1/Api/Miwebservice`. Desde el servidor evidentemente

Comment: @Yussef en el servidor IIS tengo publicadas varias paginas, si pongo localhost o 127.0.0.1 el sistema  no  va a saber a que carpeta de proyecto de pagina web estoy haciendo referencia. A no ser que en el IIS en vez de poner el DNS de la pagina lo ponga como localhost:Puerto. Si pongo localhost:puerto tengo acceso pero desde fuera del servidor nadie va a ver la pagina.

Comment: Ok, entiendo. Entonces debes solucionar el tema desde el punto de vista de "Redes", en esto no te puedo ayudar, escapa de mis conocimientos (y de la temática de este sitio). Yo partiría realizando un `tracert`

Comment: @Yussef si lanzo el tracert en el mismo servidor del IIS donde esta alojada la pagina con el nombre de la pagina la ip que va a buscar es la del mismo servidor y hay se queda. No puede la traza salir para volver a entrar