# Al publicar pagina web con IIS no puedo acceder al dominio de la pagina dentro del mismo servidor donde esta el IIS

Tags: visual-studio, iis, redes

Tengo publicada una pagina web con IIS. En el servidor donde esta el IIS no puedo acceder al dominio de la pagina.
Es decir si abro el navegador en ese servidor y coloco la url de la pagina web el navegador no la encuentra. Si lo hago en una maquina externa a esa red si que puedo navegar.

¿ Hay alguna manera de arreglar esto ?

Comment: Revisar bien el DNS de la tarjeta de red del servidor IIS.

Comment: @fredyfx que tengo que entrar en el DNS de la tarjeta de red del servidor, o en que opción o menu del IIS puedo revisarlo ?

Answer (score 0):

He encontrado una solución a medias ya que funciona si como url indico https://localhost seguido de un puerto.

Dentro del IIS, carpeta Sitios, ya dentro del sitio, voy a "Modificar sitios" y en enlaces añado a los que hay 2 nuevos nombre de host:

Tipo: https, Nombre de host: localhost, Puerto:8900 (un puerto libre )y  Direccion IP: *
En la parte de certificado SSL elijo el IIS Express Development Certificate

Tipo: http, Nombre de host: localhost, Puerto:8901 (otro puerto libre )y  Direccion IP: *

Desde el navegador del servidor IIS ahora puedo acceder si pongo la ruta:

```
"https://localhost:8900/Mipaginaweb"
```

Externamente se puede acceder a la pagina con la URL publica:

```
"https://www.MiWeb.com/Mipaginaweb"
```

A pesar que también he añadido el enlace Tipo "http" este no funciona si quiero acceder a la url con "http://"